# Mysql - Is it possible to run JSON functions on non JSON column types

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know if it's possible to run json functions (specifically json_contains), on non json column types in Mysql?
I have 'json' data stored in a varchar column, and would like to use the json mysql functions on the data.

If not is is possible to convert the data to json before using the functions?

Comment: I would give it a try and then look at any error messages to find this out for myself

Comment: _I have 'json' data stored in a varchar column_ So create a JSON Column and update the new column with the data from the VARCHAR column. Then you have a JSON column containing JSON and you dont need to know the answer to the first question

Comment: You can easily use a value of any string type as an argument to any JSON function. If the string value is not a valid JSON (check), the function returns NULL, otherwise you will get the same result as for the argument with the JSON data type.

Comment: That's where I was falling over - I needed to check if the data was valid json, THEN use the Json function

Answer (score 0):

To confirm - this was solved with

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits
WHERE json_valid(fruits.name)
  AND json_contains(fruits.name, '"Apple"')
```